# Handling form submissions in Plone templates

Tags: python, plone

I have a page template with a view class. In the page template, I have a button that submits to the same page i.e.

```
<form method="post" tal:attributes="action request/getURL" >
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="" tal:attributes="value python:item['filename']" />
    <input type="submit" name="form.action.convert" value="Convert" /> 
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the view class is called.

```
class Html(BrowserView):

    def __init__(self, context, request): 
        self.request = request
        self.context = context         

    def __call__(self):
        # Is this a form submission via POST?
        req = self.request
        if req.get('REQUEST_METHOD', 'POST') and \
            req.form.get('form.action.convert', '') == 'Convert': 

            self.convert_document(self.context, str(req.form.get('filename', '')))


    def convert_document(self, contextObj, fileToConvert):
       """ Do something """
       return None
```

Now, the problem is I cannot put the logic in the `__init__` method since this method is called multiple times, resulting in multiple form submissions with just a single click. However, the `__call__` method is called once when the button is clicked, but unfortunately, if I click a link to view the current content item in the view, nothing happens, since the `__call__` method is called and nothing happens.

I cannot use the code below in the `__call__` method. The browser will complain that the page is redirecting in a manner that will never end.

```
self.context.REQUEST.response.redirect( self.context.absolute_url() )
```

Is there a BETTER way of handling form submissions in a page template in Plone? How do I call my method (i.e. `convert_document` ) in the view class from the page template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, some comments on your code, it can be simplified and improved:

Best practice is for your form to use the `absolute_url()` method of your view; it's the canonical URL, while `request/getURL` might include acquisition oddities or the wrong URL altogether if your view was included elsewhere:

```
<form method="post" tal:attributes="action view/absolute_url" >
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="" tal:attributes="value item/filename" />
    <input type="submit" name="form.action.convert" value="Convert" /> 
</form>
```

The `filename` input box tal expression can just use a path expression, these work for dictionaries just fine.

You don't need to redefine the `__init__` method, the `BrowserView` class already provides that for you.

To test if a form has been submitted, we generally just test for the submit button being present in the request, your test is more elaborate than is needed:

```
def __call__(self):
    if 'form.action.convert' in self.request.form: 
        self.convert_document()
```

Because `convert_document` is a method of your view, it can itself access `self.context` and `self.request.form['filename']`, simplifying your method signature. Since you now know that your form is submitted, you can count on `self.request.form['filename']` to exist and be a string; if it isn't someone has been manually tinkering with the request and things deserve to break, so I generally do not use `get(..., '')` in such cases.

Views must always do all their work in the `__call__` method, since the `__init__` is called during traversal, at which time such crucial information as the current user have not yet been determined. You do not need to access the response for the `redirect` method through the context, just access it from the `self.request` attribute, but remember to *return* the result:

```
return self.request.response.redirect(self.context.absolute_url())
```

However, if your view is the *default* view of the context object, that will indeed lead to a redirect loop that the browser will not tolerate.

Note that if you do override the `__call__` method of a `BrowserView` view class that has a template associated with it, you need to make sure you return the output of the template where appropriate. My stab at your view class would thus be:

```
class Html(BrowserView):
    def __call__(self):
        if 'form.action.convert' in self.request:
            self.convert_document()
            return self.request.response.redirect(self.context.absolute_url())
        return self.index()

    def convert_document(self):
       """ Do something """
       context = self.context
       filename = self.request.form['filename']
       # Do something with the context and filename
```

Comment: THANK YOU for your careful analysis of my code. Just shows how much I still do not know regarding Plone. Baby steps. If only I had half your knowledge. Regarding your answer, YES, it worked beautifully. I was missing self.index()